# std::function parameter subclass

Tags: c++, c++11

I've trying to avoid C-style function pointers in favor of std::function objects, but I'm having problems calling member functions while inheriting.

I have a method that receives a std::function:

```
class A
{
public:
    void testCallbackA();

    // this is unrelated, but I need some features from the superclass
    void goingToNeedThisWhenCallingTestCallbackA(int someParams); 
};

void method(std::function<void(A*)> callback);

method(&A::testCallbackA); // this works fine
```

All good by now, But when I want to use A subclasses with method I need to cast the function pointer:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void testCallbackB() { }
};

method(&B::testCallbackB); // this fails

std::function<void(A*)> call = &B::testCallbackB; // this fails
std::function<void(B*)> call = &B::testCallbackB; // this works
```

If I want to be able to call method(&B::testCallbackB) I need to typedef a function pointer and cast it this way:

```
typedef void (A::*Callback)();

std::function<void(A*)> call = (Callback)&B::testCallbackB; // this works
```

Can I avoid this typedef? Can I avoid the cast? I've tried looking into std::bind with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), like in

```
B b;
method(std::bind(&B::testCallbackB, b));
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you explain a bit further how can I do this with more parameters but without setting them from the outside of method?

Answer (score 5):

This conversion *should* fail, because it's a bad idea. `std::function<void(A*)>` is callable with *any* `A*`, regardless of whether or not the actual object pointed to is a `B`. The result of calling a `B` member function on an `A` that is not a `B` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I want to call the method on B, which is an A.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, then I suggest you to make testCallbackA in class A **virtual**, and then simply use &A::testCallbackA when calling method.

*Dynamic method dispatch* will take care of calling the method of the actual class, and you do not have to circumvent type safety by hand.